# pyplot change pie slice font

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to create a basic pie chart similar to this:

http://matplotlib.org/1.2.1/examples/pylab_examples/pie_demo.html

```
from pylab import *

# make a square figure and axes
figure(1, figsize=(6,6))
ax = axes([0.1, 0.1, 0.8, 0.8])

# The slices will be ordered and plotted counter-clockwise.
labels = 'Frogs', 'Hogs', 'Dogs', 'Logs'
colors = 'black', 'blue', 'green', 'red'
fracs = [15, 30, 45, 10]
explode=(0, 0.05, 0, 0)

pie(fracs, explode=explode, labels=labels, colors=colors
                autopct='%1.1f%%', shadow=True, startangle=90)

title('Raining Hogs and Dogs', bbox={'facecolor':'0.8', 'pad':5})

show()
```

However one of my slices will be Black and I'd like to change the font just for that slice. I've looked around but can't find any instruction to just change one slice.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

what you can do is:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.gridspec import GridSpec

# Some data

labels = 'Frogs', 'Hogs', 'Dogs', 'Logs'
fracs = [15, 30, 45, 10]
colors = 'black', 'blue', 'green', 'red'
explode = (0, 0.05, 0, 0)

pie_colours = plt.pie(fracs, labels=labels, colors=colors,
                                autopct='%.0f%%',
                                shadow=True,)# radius=0.5)

pie_colours[2][0].set_color('y')
# Make the labels on the small plot easier to read.
for texts in pie_colours[1]:
    texts.set_size('smaller')
for autotexts in pie_colours[2]:
    autotexts.set_size('x-small')

plt.show()
```

I edited [this example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/pie_demo2.html) to get that.

Comment: Thanks. I tried that but got the following error:     pie_colours[0].set_color('y')

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'set_color'

Comment: But you don't have a problem for `set_size` ?

Comment: Can you edit your question with the code you have now?

Comment: set_size gives the same error. Here's the line I use to create 'pie_colours': pie_colours = pie(colour_counts[:8], labels=colors, colors=colors, explode=explode, autopct='%1.1f%%')

Comment: Normaly `autotexts[x]` should be of type `matplotlib.text.Text` not of type `list`

Comment: and if you try `pie_coloyrs[2][0].set_colors('y')`

Comment: I edited my answer: 

You are receiving a list of arguments in `pie_colours` (what i had as `patches`, `texts` and `autotexts`). So you need to loop in these lists of `matplotlib.text.Text`

Comment: Perfect! That works great. I can individually set font colours for each slice now. Thanks for your help.